# Show a retrieved img from Firebase with Angular in HTML

Tags: html, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

First of all sorry my English!
I will try to explain it, it's a very noob question but that's what I am right now with angular and html.
I retrieved an object from my firebase database which is a string containing an image source (http://picture.....png). How do I use it to make it the src of a html img?

This is my code:

HTML:

```
            <span *ngIf="chat.from !== uid">
              <ol class="chat">
                <li class="self">
                        <div class="avatar"><img src="picture" **<--- here goes the retrieved picture** draggable="false"/></div>
                      <div class="msg">
                        <p>{{ chat.message }}</p> 
                        <time>{{ chat.time }}</time>
                      </div>
                </li>
              </ol>
          </span> 
         </span>
```

user-provider with angular code:

```
  getUserPicture(company: string, userid: string) { 
  return this.getUid().then(uid => {
    return this.db.object(`companies/${company}/users/${uid}/sPicture`);
});
}
```

user page:

```
    openChat(key) { 
    this.userProvider.getCompany().then(company => { 
        this.userProvider.getUserPicture(company, key).then(picture => {
            let param = {company: company,uid: this.uid, interlocutor: key, picture: picture};
            this.nav.push(ChatViewPage,param);    
        }) 
});
```

When I print it it shows:

```
this.picture = params.data.picture;

console.log: picture = [object Object]
```

So I'm pretty sure it is retrieved ok. Do I need to convert it to string? How do I set the src img to be that picture?

I hope you can understand me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the returned element has a string property which contains an absoluth link to a resource in some server (http.../image.jpg for example) you could create a img in the following way:

```
<img [src]="componentProperty"></img>
```